# Spring security login error page, access denied

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-oauth2

When I login into my oauth2 protected form with invalid credentials, the redirect to the default login error page 'login?error' does not work. In my logs I can see:

```
2018-02-01 10:58:35.935 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-8] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
2018-02-01 10:58:35.935 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-8] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@49d1bcfd
2018-02-01 10:58:35.935 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-8] .a.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler : Redirecting to /login?error
2018-02-01 10:58:35.935 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-8] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to '/uaa/login?error'
```

But after the redirect there is an 'Access denied' exception:

```
2018-02-01 10:58:35.943 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /login?error=; Attributes: [authenticated]
2018-02-01 10:58:35.943 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6fa90ed4: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffc7f0c: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 03550F34462ABD6D42B5E224A4C478F9; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2018-02-01 10:58:35.943 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@337e3785, returned: -1
2018-02-01 10:58:35.943 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

Followed by a redirect to the login page again '/login'

```
2018-02-01 10:58:35.943 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**', GET]
2018-02-01 10:58:35.943 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request '/login' matched by universal pattern '/**'
2018-02-01 10:58:35.944 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']]
2018-02-01 10:58:35.944 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2018-02-01 10:58:35.944 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true
2018-02-01 10:58:35.944 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@27122376, matchingMediaTypes=[application/json], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]
2018-02-01 10:58:35.944 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : httpRequestMediaTypes=[text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2018-02-01 10:58:35.944 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing text/html
2018-02-01 10:58:35.944 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith text/html = false
2018-02-01 10:58:35.944 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing application/xhtml+xml
2018-02-01 10:58:35.944 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith application/xhtml+xml = false
2018-02-01 10:58:35.944 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing image/webp
2018-02-01 10:58:35.944 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith image/webp = false
2018-02-01 10:58:35.944 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing image/apng
2018-02-01 10:58:35.944 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith image/apng = false
2018-02-01 10:58:35.944 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing application/xml;q=0.9
2018-02-01 10:58:35.944 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith application/xml;q=0.9 = false
2018-02-01 10:58:35.944 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing */*;q=0.8
2018-02-01 10:58:35.944 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Ignoring
2018-02-01 10:58:35.944 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Did not match any media types
2018-02-01 10:58:35.944 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true
2018-02-01 10:58:35.948 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]]
2018-02-01 10:58:35.948 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true
2018-02-01 10:58:35.948 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : All requestMatchers returned true
2018-02-01 10:58:35.948 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://localhost:8765/uaa/login?error=]
2018-02-01 10:58:35.948 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
2018-02-01 10:58:35.948 DEBUG 17600 --- [http-nio-8899-exec-10] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to 'http://localhost:8765/uaa/login'
```

Does someone have an idea whats going wrong?

Edit: Add security configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Order(-20)
protected static class LoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/static/**", "/images/**", "/fonts/**", "/health", "/info");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/console/**", "/reset").permitAll()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access", "/reset")
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```

Another edit: When I access the oauth2 server directly without going trough Zuul, the redirect to the login error page 'login?error' page works.

Zuul's security configuration is

```
   @Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
        .logout()
        .permitAll()
        .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK))
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/uaa/**", "/login", "/xxx/view3/**", "/*/view404", "/*/view403").permitAll()
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/xxx/**/*").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/yyy/**/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
        .csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(csrfRequestMatcher()).csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
    .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());
    // @formatter:on
}
```

Edit: Added trace of requests

HAR-Export from Chrome DEV-Tools: [Just share it](https://justpaste.it/1gid4)

Just paste it in here to visualize: [HAR viewer](http://www.softwareishard.com/har/viewer/)

Comment: The redirect logs are from Oauth2 server.

Comment: By Oauth2 server I mean the service (called uaa-service) which acts as both, authorization server and resource server. The Context path is /uaa, correct. My setup is similar to https://github.com/kakawait/uaa-behind-zuul-sample/blob/master/api-gateway/src/main/resources/application.yml

So Zuul does forward the requests.

Comment: The only difference between the URLs is the port:
Zuul: http://localhost:8765/uaa/login
UAA: http://localhost:8899/uaa/login

Comment: Yes, http://localhost:8765/uaa/login?error does the redirect to /login http://localhost:8899/uaa/login?error shows the error message which is parsed if the query string 'error' is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add

```
.antMatchers("/console/**", "/reset", "/login").permitAll()
```

to the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter of the uaa-service. Final working configuration

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/console/**", "/reset", "/login").permitAll()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access", "/reset")
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

If someone could explain why this is necessary, this would be nice.

Comment: Oh, maybe I see the problem. Zuul adds a `=` to the redirection URL: `/login?error=`. It should only be `/login?error`. Adding the `antMatcher` pattern works, because it ignores any query string.

Comment: So do you consider this as a bug in Zuul or is it some miss configuration on my side? Thank you for your time and support.